# Trying to add to fechaProceso(localDate) they days which are not in weekends Java

Tags: java

```
LocalDate fechaProceso = r.getFechaProceso();
DayOfWeek dow;
Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
Boolean todayIsWeekend;
LocalDate fechaValor = null;
int i = 1;
while (i <= corr.getDiasValor()) {
    fechaValor = fechaProceso.plusDays(i);  
    dow = fechaValor.getDayOfWeek(); 
    todayIsWeekend = weekend.contains(dow); 
    if (todayIsWeekend) {
        fechaValor.plusDays(2);
    }
    i++;
}
```

What I am trying to do is add to a date(fechaValor) one day but when it is in order to ignore those days. That is, if I am on `Friday 2021-09-10` and I want to add one more day than add two more (that is, skipping Saturday and Sunday) and going to `Monday`, that is, the next day would be `2021-09-13`.
What can i do? Actually my code is not working

**EDIT2**(not working neither):

```
            switch (fechaProceso.getDayOfWeek()) {
            // when it's a Friday, then add three days to get next Monday
            case FRIDAY:
                fechaValor = fechaProceso.plusDays(corr.getDiasValor() + 3) ;
            // on Saturday, add 2 days
            case SATURDAY:
                fechaValor = fechaProceso.plusDays(corr.getDiasValor() + 2) ;
            // in all other cases add just 1 day
            default:
                fechaValor = fechaProceso.plusDays(corr.getDiasValor() + 1) ;
        }
```

Comment: You are checking the `DayOfWeek` of `fechaProceso` and then adding days for next business day plus `corr.getDiasValor()`. If `corr.getDiasValor() != 0` you will get back any day (including `SATURDAY`and `SUNDAY` depending on the value of `corr.getDiasValor() `). Try the switch with 'fechaProceso.plusDays(corr.getDiasValor())' and then add days to that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
    .parse( "2021-09-10" )  // Friday
    .with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() )  // Monday
```

> 2021-09-13

## `TemporalAdjuster`

To move to another date, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). Some implementations are bundled with Java, and you can write your own as well.

### Next Monday

In your case, Java provides [`TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

```
Set< LocalDate > weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
LocalDate x = LocalDate.parse( "2021-09-10" ) ;  // Friday
LocalDate y = x.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Saturday
if( weekend.contains( y.getDayOfWeek() ) )
{
    y = y.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;  // Monday
}
```

As mentioned, you could alternatively implement this logic by writing your own `TemporalAdjuster` implementation. You would name it something like `nextWorkingDay`.

Oh, hold on! Somebody already wrote that for you. Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to get [`org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay()), a `TemporalAdjuster`.

```
LocalDate x = LocalDate.parse( "2021-09-10" ) ;  // Friday
LocalDate y = x.with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() );  // Monday
```

Note that this `org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay` adjuster is hard-coded for Saturday-Sunday. It is not locale-sensitive, for regions using a different definition of weekend. For that you would write your own temporal adjuster.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a method that returns the next working day when you pass it a `LocalDate` as an argument:

```
public static LocalDate getNextWorkday(LocalDate localDate, long daysToAdd) {
    long i = 0;
    LocalDate resultingWorkday = localDate;
    while (i < daysToAdd) {
        switch (localDate.getDayOfWeek()) {
        // when it's a Friday, then add three days to get next Monday
        case FRIDAY:
            resultingWorkday.plusDays(3);
        // on Saturday, add 2 days
        case SATURDAY:
            resultingWorkday.plusDays(2);
        // in all other cases add just 1 day
        default:
            resultingWorkday.plusDays(1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return resultingWorkday;
}
```

When you try this in a `main` with your example date, like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("2021-09-10");
    long daysToAdd = 5;
    LocalDate nextWorkday = getNextWorkday(ld, daysToAdd);
    System.out.println("Having added " 
            + daysToAdd 
            + " workdays: " 
            + nextWorkday.format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, uuuu-MM-dd",
                            Locale.ENGLISH)));
}
```

you get the output

```
Having added 5 workdays: Fri, 2021-09-10
```

Comment: corr.getDiasValor() is the value which i'm adding to the date, so when it's fryday im addin ccor.GetDiasValor() + 3, saturday 2... but not working @deHaar

Comment: Have a look at the new edit, maybe that's working for you... Let me know, please, @okjfokjrf

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the `DayOfWeek` of `fechaProceso` and then adding days for next business day plus `corr.getDiasValor()`. You should add the days before and then check for weekends.

```
public LocalDate adjust(LocalDate date, int days) {
    LocalDate dateAdjusted = date.plusDays(days);
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = dateAdjusted.getDayOfWeek();
    if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
        return dateAdjusted.plusDays(2);
    } else if (dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        return dateAdjusted.plusDays(1);
    } else {
        return dateAdjusted;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, 9, 6);
    
IntStream.range(0, 7).forEach(days -> System.out.println(adjust(date, days)));
```

Output:

```
2021-09-06
2021-09-07
2021-09-08
2021-09-09
2021-09-10
2021-09-13
2021-09-13
```